# Bootstrap: positioning div block under col-xs-8 + col-xs-4 is not as expected

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0 and my question is:

can this block

```
<div class="under col-xs-12">fdf</div>
```

be placed in the code the way as it is shown here

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">aaa</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">bbb</div>
    <div class="under col-xs-12">fdf</div>
</div>
```

so that the text `fdf` is under `aaa` and `bbb`
I think it anyway should be  under, as col-xs-8 + col-xs-4 cover the whole width, however I'm confused as

```
div.under{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

wraps not just one block `fdf`, but the whole content including `aaa` and `bbb`.

You may take a look here:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4480/)

So, what's the proper way, from Bootstrap prospective, to make that black border wrap only the second line `fdf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `aaa` and `bbb` columns are floated, so you need to add `clear:both;` to your under class.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DTcHh/4482/)**

Answer (score 2):

**Bootstrap way of doing this**

This is a similar answer as [one posted by j08691](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28608586/3556874), But you are using Bootstrap so we will look at the Bootstrap way of doing this

> Bootstrap has provided its own built-in class `clearfix` for this
>   pupose(to clear the float)

see this: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4487/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">aaa</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">bbb</div>
    <div class='clearfix'></div>
    <div class="under col-xs-12 ">fdf</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the "Bootstrap way" is to make a nested row. See how they did it here under "Nested Scaffolding": http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">aaa</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">bbb</div>
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="under col-xs-12">fdf</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is wrong. Adding a nested row like that causes the content to float off to the left. `.row` has a negative margin, which is offset by the `.col`'s positive margin. Putting a `.row` in a `.row` will cause a double negative margin, which is then not properly offset by the `.col`. See http://www.bootply.com/smqptoi0Jj if you're confused.

Answer (score 1):

And what about creating an other row?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">aaa</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">bbb</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="under col-xs-12">fdf</div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this is the right approach, sometimes when adding columns dynamically, you can't know when to add a row.